# Can anyone point me to a AMF library in either Delphi or FreePascal?

Tags: flash, delphi, amf, freepascal, fpc

I've done a simple search on the usual suspects(Google Code, Source Forge, SO) but did not find any hints of a project for AMF or Flash/Flex remoting.

Has anyone stumbled on a project of this nature?

Answer (score 0):

On [*CodeRage 4*](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/coderage/sessions) Kim Madsen presented 'Integrating Delphi with Flex/Flash/AIR using kbmMW
'. On Thursday, September 10, 2009 from 6:00am - 6:45am. Maybe it is of interest for you.